# How to know the index on the view port of ItemsRepeater

Tags: xaml, uwp, focus

I'm using `ItemsRepeater`, the whole design is almost like NetFlix's home page, with a vertical `ItemsRepeater`, and horizotal `ItemsRepeater` in each vertical template.

Now if I want to move focus from A to B, ignoring each item's real index, just count the index on the view port.

So how to know A and B's view port index.

The reason why I want this is:
On Apple TV, their `FocusManager` can find the nearest focusable element while scrolling fast.

But on Xbox, If I have a menu button the the left-top, then scroll fast from A to B, `FocusManager` will return Menu button as the next focusable element, not item B.
Even if I remove menu button, the `FocusManager` will return null sometimes.

This is annoying.

[image]

Comment: So the problem only occurs in x-box platform? could you share a code sample for us?

Comment: Only xbox need focus,  I will share a repo later.

Comment: Great, I will test your  sample.